# how deep Keras works with NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I know that Keras works numpy arrays (for example setting weights for layers in your model). But what if I wrote my own [Python type](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html), and then make it compatible
with [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/c-info.beyond-basics.html#user-defined-data-types). Would that be enough for Keras to accept my custom type or I have to do some extra steps?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: This is more general question. At this point am in the progress of writing my own type. I would like to create python wrapper around C++ [class](https://github.com/LiraNuna/soft-ieee754). But if you want some already working python types that are compatible with [Numpy](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/numtypes). There are just examples that I have found online.

Comment: With my knowledge, Keras backend will be Tensorflow, Pytorch or Theano. I have no experience with Theano, but Tf and torch use "Tensor" type, and numpy is "array" type. You need to convert your numpy array to Tensor, and Keras will accept that variable.

Comment: @Toby pytorch is not a keras backend, and there is very slim chance of happening that in future.